# Removing nodata value from raster images?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, nodata

I'm doing urban change prediction in Land Change Modeler (TerrSet software), and i can't run Transition Sub-Model.

I don't know why, but I think it is because I have nodata value in Variable (slope image, elevation image, distance to roads) and I don't know how I can remove these values.

I tried in ArcGIS (reclass, copy raster).

Nodata value is -3,402823e+038

Comment: Does your raster have NoData? you have a NoData value set but do any pixels *actually* have that value? Do you have cells with a different value you want to be NoData? What is the raster type (GRID, Tiff, img etc..) and pixel type of your raster? Are there any specific error messages? A rough stab-in-the-dark: could be because your raster is floating point and the model expects classifed and attributed integer raster.

Comment: Raster is img. type, pixel type is floating , and I must convert to raster format (rst.) in TerrSet...error message is "Error in command line"....when I show nodata value in ArcGis in red color, data(raster's) frame shows in red...i tried unsinged integer of pixel value, but I have same error message

Answer (score 6):

There is a useful method using `Con` and `IsNull` statements in the raster calculator to convert NoData to a different value.

[HowTo:  Convert NoData values to other values for raster data](http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34932)

[image]

Comment: I can vouch that this method works as I have used it many times.

Comment: I tried but I still have nodata value (now is -32768)

Answer (score 3):

[@Aaron's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159832) might be the best solution for general raster files (thematic or continuous data). If you have a thematic raster you could also use the Reclassify tool (see below). In the example NoData will be replaced with 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply Abs tool with raster calculator